# Anaconda navigator (64-bit) doesn't start

Tags: python, anaconda

I don't really now what's happening but I'm trying to start the Anaconda Navigator on my Windows 10 laptop but it doesn't start. I click the icon and nothing happen. So I tried to start it form the command line, here the output:

```
(base) C:\Users\stram\Anaconda3\Scripts>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stram\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\stram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\stram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\stram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

How it is possible that it's missing some module, it just worked fine until a day ago! The only thing I did was updating the new version of Spyder. However I tried to install PySide and I get the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\stram\Anaconda3\Scripts>pip install -U PySide
Collecting PySide
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/ac/ca31db6f2225844d37a41b10615c3d371587677efd074db29855e7035de6/PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\stram\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\stram\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wv8ecv8t\\PySide\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\stram\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wv8ecv8t\\PySide\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\stram\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wv8ecv8t\PySide\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\stram\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wv8ecv8t\PySide\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Looks like it doesn't support my version of python:

```
(base) C:\Users\stram\Anaconda3\Scripts>conda -V
conda 4.8.0

(base) C:\Users\stram\Anaconda3\Scripts>python -V
Python 3.7.6
```

But I don't understand how it is possible , I don't remember updating python. What should I do, revert to an older python version (3.4)? If there no other solution, how do I do that?

Edit: I also tried to unistall anaconda and re-install it but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

PySide comes with a warning that it might not work correctly with python 3.7 as well as on windows OS. You might have to downgrade your python version in conda base to 3.5 or 3.4. You may consider PySide2 with python 3.6

Comment: I tried to install PySide2 and it installed successfully, but when I try to launch  I still get the same error, still looking for PySide.

Ho cna I make it look for PySide2 or How cna I downgrade to Python 3.5?